# rails g active_admin:install not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

I am just starting with Ruby on rails and trying to setup active_admin. So after installing the gem I got the following error.

```
Could not find erubi-1.7.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

The erubi-1.7.0 is already installed but it still not able to find it. Here are the gems that gets installed when I run bundle install.

```
Using rake 12.1.0
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
Using i18n 0.8.6
Using minitest 5.10.3
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using builder 3.2.3
**Using erubi 1.7.0**
Using mini_portile2 2.3.0
Using crass 1.0.2
Using rack 2.0.3
Using nio4r 2.1.0
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.2
Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using method_source 0.9.0
Using thor 0.20.0
Using formtastic_i18n 0.6.0
Using kaminari-core 1.0.1
Using arel 8.0.0
Using rb-fsevent 0.10.2
Using ffi 1.9.18
Using public_suffix 3.0.0
Using bcrypt 3.1.11
Using bindex 0.5.0
Using bundler 1.15.4
Using byebug 9.1.0
Using cancan 1.6.10
Using mini_mime 0.1.4
Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
Using request_store 1.3.2
Using multi_json 1.12.2
Using ruby_dep 1.5.0
Using puma 3.10.0
Using rubyzip 1.2.1
Using tilt 2.0.8
Using sqlite3 1.3.13
Using turbolinks-source 5.0.3
Using tzinfo 1.2.3
Using nokogiri 1.8.1
Using rack-test 0.7.0
Using sprockets 3.7.1
Using warden 1.2.7
Using websocket-driver 0.6.5
Using mime-types 3.1
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using uglifier 3.2.0
Using rb-inotify 0.9.10
Using childprocess 0.8.0
Using addressable 2.5.2
Using turbolinks 5.0.1
Using activesupport 5.1.4
Using loofah 2.1.1
Using xpath 2.1.0
Using mail 2.6.6
Using sass-listen 4.0.0
Using listen 3.1.5
Using selenium-webdriver 3.6.0
Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
Using globalid 0.4.0
Using arbre 1.1.1
Using activemodel 5.1.4
Using jbuilder 2.7.0
Using pundit 1.1.0
Using spring 2.0.2
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
Using capybara 2.15.4
Using sass 3.5.2
Using activejob 5.1.4
Using activerecord 5.1.4
Using activemodel-serializers-xml 1.0.2
Using spring-watcher-listen 2.0.1
Using actionview 5.1.4
Using kaminari-activerecord 1.0.1
Using polyamorous 1.3.1
Using actionpack 5.1.4
Using kaminari-actionview 1.0.1
Using actioncable 5.1.4
Using actionmailer 5.1.4
Using railties 5.1.4
Using formtastic 3.1.5
Using has_scope 0.7.1
Using ransack 1.8.4
Using draper 3.0.0
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
Using kaminari 1.0.1
Using coffee-rails 4.2.2
Using responders 2.4.0
Using jquery-rails 4.3.1
Using web-console 3.5.1
Using rails 5.1.4
Using sass-rails 5.0.6
Using inherited_resources 1.7.2
Using devise 4.3.0
Using activeadmin 1.1.0
```

Can someone plz help with the possible solution for this?

Comment: Try removing the Gemfile.lock, removing the erubi gem and running bundle again `rm -rf Gemfile.lock && gem uninstall erubi && bundle`.

Comment: I tried that. I removed the Gemfile.lock, uninstall all the gems, and then reinstall using bundle install but still facing with the issue.

Comment: Have you just upgraded from Rails 4 to Rails 5 by any chance?  You tagged this question ruby-on-rails4, which uses erubis, not erubi, but the gems installed above are Rails 5.1.  Are you using rvm? gemsets? `bundle exec rails server`?

Comment: No it's Rails 5.1 only. I put the tag by mistake. Corrected it now. Yaa I am using rvm gemset.